# Mean and Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, descriptive-statistics

Thirty-seven in one hundred travellers named “crying kids” as the most annoying on a flight.

You randomly select eight people and asked them if crying kids are the most annoying on a flight.

Compute the mean and the variance respectively.

Is the answer this 2.96(mean), 1.8648(variance) or 2.96(mean), 1.0952(variance).

Comment: how did you arrive at this solution?

Comment: This is a MCQ question asked by my friend to call me to solve but I do not know how to solve. This is all the MCQ choices: a)2.96, 1.8648, b)29.6, 10.952, c)296, 18 648, d)2.96, 1.0952 @Alex

Comment: Okok. Sorry. Will take note of it.

Comment: When you want to compute mean and variance of a random variable, you really need to mention also what the random variable is. Do you realize that it (presumably) is the number of people in the sample who are crying kids?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is the whole question asked me by my friend @rschwieb

Comment: @user119884 Sorry, I take it back. You'll be interested in probabilities, but that's not the solution to the problem.

Comment: This is a MCQ question asked by my friend to call me to solve but I do not know how to solve. This is all the MCQ choices: a)2.96, 1.8648, b)29.6, 10.952, c)296, 18 648, d)2.96, 1.0952 @rschwieb

Comment: The number $X$ of people in the sample who find crying kids the most annoying has *binomial distribution*, variance $np(1-p)$, where $n=8$ and $p=0.37$.

Answer (score 0):

$37$ in $100 = 37\%$, $n=8, p=0.37, q=0.63$

mean $\quad = np
     =8 \times 0.37
     = 2.96$

variance $=npq=8\times0.37\times0.63=1.8648$

Answer : $2.96$ and $1.8648$